# Write ODF Spreadsheet documents with ODFDOM Java API

Tags: java, spreadsheet, java-module, java-platform-module-system, odf

I want to update an old program from Java 8 to Java 15 with modules and therefore I rewrite and update a lot of code. Everything works fine until the update of the library to write spreadsheet documents.

In the old version, I used the **org.odftoolkit** with the **simple-api** with maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>odfdom-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

As described [here](https://odftoolkit.org/simple/index.html), this API is deprecated and I want to step over to the current [ODFDOM](https://odftoolkit.org/odfdom/index.html) API. But the documentation is not current with the latest version and I did not found an example for the java module.

I added the maven dependencies, but the question is how to add this to the module-info.java file. All my attempts with

```
requires org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc.table;
```

or equal ones have failed miserably.

My question may occur simply, but for me, it is a big mountain. What is the right way to do this? Thank you for any input.

Comment: *Edit*: I have removed one of the `requires` from the directive considering that was just a typo while posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Derive the module name

```
jar --file=/path/to/your/jar/odfdom-java-0.8.7.jar --describe-module
```

#### Add the directive for dependency

In your case, if these dependencies are not yet modular or declare their `Automatic-Module-Name`. You can still make use of the derived name in the module directives to make use of the public classes within the packages of the modules.

```
requires odfdom.java;
requires simple.java;
```

As the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7) of Module declaration guides:

```
requires {RequiresModifier} ModuleName ;

RequiresModifier:
(one of)
transitive static
```

you need to specify the module name instead of the packages that your code would rely upon.

Additionally, upon some research, I could find out, that you might want to test the BETA or RC version of the toolkit, as listed in the [repository tags](https://github.com/tdf/odftoolkit/tags) and maven central.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have rare time this week (snow is coming) and will take a look to it on the weekend. Likewise, I need to see if I wasn't using local jars with maven in the old version. To much time was gone so far...